# Picking a scale for floating point values in an array, does it matter for precision of arithmetic

Tags: math, floating-point, sum, precision

I have a large array of floating point values that vary widely in magnitude. Does it help rescaling those in [0,1] for precision purposes (e.g. if I want to perform arithmetic operations on the array)? I can think of the smaller values getting truncated if I do so, but on the other hand small values will not contribute much to the absolute error. If I do the rescaling on an array of already computed values, I believe this can only make things worse as I would only introduce additional round-off error. On the other hand, I believe I can decrease the error if the scaling is instead involved at the point when I generate said values.

I am mainly referring to the fact that absolute distance between consecutive error grows 2 times for values in subsequent intervals (i.e. [0,1) vs [1,2) vs [2,4), etc.). Am I interpreting this correctly in the current context? I have seen such effect of floating point errors due to large scaling when trying to render a massively scaled 3D scene versus a less scaled version of it (similar effects occur when a camera in 3D space is too far from the origin, since absolute distances between floats become larger).

Considering the above, is there an optimal way to choose the scaling factor for an array of values I plan to generate (provided I know what the minimum and maximum will be without scaling). I was thinking of just generating it so that all values are within [0,1], however I was worried that the truncation of the smallest element may be an issue. Are there known heuristics based on the largest and smallest elements that allow to find a semi-optimal rescaling wrt precision. On an unrelated note, I am aware of the Kahan summation algorithm and its variants and I do use it for the summation of said array. My question is rather whether a choice of scale can help further, or will this not matter?

Comment: "I can think of the smaller values getting truncated if I do so, " --> _scaling_ (as in y = mx) will not cause truncation.  Scaling will _not_ make things much worse.  "(i.e. [0,1) vs [1,2) vs [2,4), etc.)." is incorrect.  Perhaps you meant "(i.e. [0.5,1) vs [1,2) vs [2,4), etc.).".  You concerns are best addressed with a sample of a case you have in mind with real values, else one can only speak in broad generalities.  Note: about 25% of all FP values are in the [0,1] range.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes indeed, my bad, it was meant to be [0.5,1). As far as truncation goes, if it is a very small number then dividing by a large enough number can make it 0, in the same way as multiplying a very large number by a very larger number can make it overflow to infinity. I know the question is general, however if anyone knows any heuristics, references, or papers on the subject, that's also useful to me.

Comment: _In general_, scaling the vaules toward magnitude 1.0 helps prevent over/underflow in subsequent calculations with a loss of about 0.5 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) precision.  (that's trading range for a little precision loss)

Comment: What @chux said. The details of the computation and an example of representative data should inform the assessment of whether scaling by a power of two would confer any advantage. *Generally speaking*, you would want to avoid operating on numbers very small in magnitude, as sub-normal operands utilize only part of the available significand (mantissa) bits of a floating-point number.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Are there any references I can refer to for that, and possibly for more details?

Comment: @lightxbulb Canonical reference: Nicholas J. Higham, "Accuracy and Stability of Numerical Algorithms, Second Edition", SIAM 2002

Comment: Scaling binary floating-point numbers by a power of two (or, generally, base-b floating-point numbers by a power of b) has no net effect on the rounding errors in calculations unless you reach the ends of the exponent ranges, so that overflow or underflow occurs. This is because the arithmetic on the significands proceeds in exactly the same way regardless of the scaling. If you halve the numbers, you halve the absolute errors, but they remain identical relative to the numbers. And, at the end, when you reverse the scaling, you restore the scales of the errors.

Comment: However, you mention 3D scenes far from the origin. Then you want to consider not scaling but translation. If you have some box with its origin at (3, 4) and some other box with its origin at (1000003, 5000004), then calculations with the box farther from the origin will generally have larger errors. So it would be preferable to translate the scene closer to the origin, do the calculations, and preferably render it from the new coordinates. But even if you have to translate them back, causing some additional error in the process, the final results might be better. It depends on various things.

Comment: Aside from that, your post says almost nothing about the calculations you are going to do with these values. That matters critically to the errors that may occur.

Comment: As long as all floating-point operations involved have an ulp error bound (e.g. correctly rounded = 0.5 ulp) that is uniform across the entire input domain, @Eric Postpischil's comment applies. However, we don't know whether that is the case for asker's use case. Their computation may involve operations, such as the evaluation of transcendental functions, whose ulp error is *not* uniform across the entire input domain.

Comment: @njuffa: Comments don’t permit room for full discussion, but I was assuming all the operations were homogeneous linear with respect to the array data mentioned in the question. It would not make much sense to use sin(x) in some scenario where sin(mx) would be analogous when everything is scaled by m. E.g. OP mentions points in space. Scaling the points would not alter the angles between them, so any sines would be computed on the same angles.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for the detailed explanations. Feel free to put your comments in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I did not post it as an answer because the question does not describe what operations are performed. Whether a computation is scale-invariant or not depends on what operations are performed. E.g., addition and subtraction are scale invariant. Multiplication and division are scale-invariant when the scale is compensated for. Many other things, like trigonometric functions, are not scale-invariant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Trigonometric functions are used, but the scaling is applied to their result, not to their argument. Beyond that everything is multiplication and addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling by powers of two in a binary floating-point format (or, generally, by powers of *b* in a base-*b* floating-point format) has no error as long as the results stay within normal exponent bounds. That is, for any *x*, the result of computing *x*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup> has the same significand as *x*, as long as  *x*•*b*<sup>*e*</sup> is in the normal range.

Again as long as results stay in the normal range, the operations of adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing scaled numbers produce results with identical significands as the same operations on unscaled numbers that stay in the normal range. Any rounding errors that occur in the unscaled operations are identical to the rounding errors in the scaled operations, as adjusted by the scale.

Therefore, scaling numbers by a power of *b*, performing the same operations, and undoing the scaling will not improve or alter floating-point rounding errors. (Note that multiplications and divisions will affect the scaling, and this can be compensated for either after each operation, after all the operations, or periodically. For example, given `X = x*16` and `Y = y*16`, `X*Y` would equal `x*16*y*16` = `x*y*256`. So undoing its scaling requires dividing by 256 rather than 16.)

If other operations are used, the rounding errors may differ. For example, if a square root is performed and the scaling in its operand is not an even power of *b*, its result will include a scaling that is not an integral power of *b*, and so the significand must be different from the significand of the corresponding unscaled result, and that allows the rounding errors to be different.

Of course, if sines, cosines, or other trigonometric functions are used on scaled numbers, drastically different results will be obtained, as these functions do not scale in the required way (f(*x*•*s*) generally does not equal f(*x*)•*s*). However, if the numbers that are being scaled represent points in space, any angles computed between them would be identical in the scaled and unscaled implementations. That is, the computed angles would be free of scaling, and so applying trigonometric functions would produce identical results.

If any intermediate results exceed the normal exponent range in either the scaled or the unscaled computations, then different significands may be produced. This includes the case where the results are subnormal but have not underflowed to zero—subnormal results may have truncated signficands, so some information is lost compared to a differently-scaled computation that produces a result in the normal range.

An alternative to scaling may be translation. When working with points from the origin, the coordinates may be large, and the floating-point resolution may be large relative to distances between the points. If the points are translated to near the origin (a fixed amount is subtracted from each coordinate [fixed per dimension]), the geometric relationships between them are preserved, but the coordinates will be in a finer range of the floating-point format. This can improve the floating-point rounding errors that occur.